# Yureka plus System update showing a watermark Cyanogen Preview - 12.1-YOG4PAP8BL

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

I got the system update from CyanogenMod 12.1 YOG4PAP8BL but it is showing a watermark at the right bottom of the phone.

can some one explain how to remove it from the phone?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a preview build of the CyanogenOS 12.1 for yureka plus.
Try changing the language from English India to English UK or US.

You can visit the [official forums](http://forums.yuplaygod.com/threads/guide-how-to-yureka-yureka-plus-manual-update-cos-12-1-official-update-rolled-out.26561/) for further queries.